# Simple least squares regression problem

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm new to least squares regression, and I want to fit $y = a + x$ to the data $\{(0, 1), (1, 3), (2, 4)\}$. I found that the total sum of the squares for the dataset is

$$(1 - 2)^2 + (2 - 2)^2 + (3 - 2)^2 = 2,$$

and I found the sample mean of $y$ to be $8/3$ and the mean of $x$ to be $1$. So I found $\hat{\beta}$ to be

$$\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})(y_i - \overline{y})}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}(x_i - \overline{x})^2} = \frac{(0 - 1)(1 - 8/3) + (1 - 1) (\cdots) + (2 - 1)(4 - 8/3)}{2} = 3/2$$

And then $\hat{\alpha}$ is just $\overline{y} - \hat{\beta}\overline{x} = 8/3 - 3/2 = 7/6$.

So my line is $y = 7/6 + x$.  Is that right? It seems a little bit wrong because I plotted the three points and the line, and I feel like the line should be a little bit higher up.

Comment: This is a small enough problem that you can do the partial derivatives and $\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$ by hand to check your work. // Depending on how the evening goes and who else responds, I might post an answer going through those.

Comment: If you "found the sample mean of $y$ to be $8/3$ and the mean of $x$ to be $1$" and you want your line to pass through the mean point then I would have thought $\hat a=\bar y-\bar x = \frac53$

Comment: @Henry I think you might be right. Because setting $a = 5/3$ minimizes the sum of squares of residuals. I set the equation up in terms of $a$ and took a derivative and got $5/3$. Also, the line seems to be a better fit when I plot it.